# Where do I place sitemap for fourth level domain?

Tags: sitemap

Where should I place sitemap.xml file in case of fourth level domain (e.g. en.subdomain.example.com)?

From [sitemaps.org](https://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_location):

> All URLs listed in the Sitemap must reside on the same host as the
>   Sitemap. For instance, if the Sitemap is located at
>   http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml, it can't include URLs from
>   http://subdomain.example.com. If the Sitemap is located at
>   http://www.example.com/myfolder/sitemap.xml, it can't include URLs
>   from http://www.example.com.

Does it mean that I should place different sitemap.xml file at the root directory of each subdomain? E.g:

```
example.com/sitemap.xml - for links ~ https://example.com/path
subdomain1.example.com/sitemap.xml - for links ~ https://subdomain1.example.com/path
subdomain2.example.com/sitemap.xml - for links ~ https://subdomain2.example.com/path
en.subdomain1.example.com/sitemap.xml - for links ~ https://en.subdomain1.example.com/path
fr.subdomain2.example.com/sitemap.xml - for links ~ https://fr.subdomain2.example.com/path
```

Currently I have one sitemap.xml file at the root of https://example.com/, which includes all links from all subdomains.